# Creating multidimensional matrix in python using for loop

Tags: python, matlab, for-loop, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm slowly learning the differences between MATLAB and Python, and wanted to know how I could do the following, which was done in MATLAB, in Python instead:

```
Ak = zeros(3,3,N);
for t = 1:N
    Ak(:,:,t) = [
    a(t) 0 0;
    0 a(t) 0;
    0 0 a(t);
    ];
end
```

Where `a(t)` is just a vector with `N` elements. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but that MATLAB code is ugly! See the `diag` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NumPy for matrix calculation. Here is an example.

```
import numpy as np
N = 256
a = np.arange(N)
Ak = np.zeros((3,3,N))
for t in range(N):
    Ak[:,:,t] = np.array([[a[t], 0, 0],
                          [0, a[t], 0],
                          [0, 0, a[t]]])
```

If you use Ak with different dimension order, like [N, 3, 3], you can simplify the code a little.

```
import numpy as np
N = 256
a = np.arange(N)
Ak = np.zeros((N,3,3))
for ak, _a in zip(Ak, a):
    ak[:, :] = np.array([[_a, 0, 0],
                         [0, _a, 0],
                         [0, 0, _a]])
```

Comment: Thanks dkato, as an aside, why did you use `np.array()` to define the matrix? Would if produce different results in output and/or runtime if I didn't affix that term to my matrix?

Comment: I think the code without `np.array` produces the same result. But, in Python, nested brackets, like '`[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`', produces list of list, which differs from 2d-array. So, I added `np.array` so that it explicitly indicate you are assigning 2d-array.